# Sticky Nav - Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

I'm trying to implement this on my site so the nav style changes as you scroll into corresponding sections.

http://stanhub.com/sticky-header-change-navigation-active-class-on-page-scroll-with-jquery/

The only difference I can see is that I am creating a nav that becomes sticky after it reaches the top of the page.

When I throw in a

```
console.log(refElement.position())
```

I get this

```
Object {top: 716.984375, left: 50.5}
Object {top: 1811.796875, left: 50.5}
```

I am getting the error

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined" on from function.
```

On this line:

```
if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
```

Here's the script

```
$(document).ready(function() {    

    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('.cn17w1.original a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('.cn17w1.original ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));`

This is going to return an empty jQuery set, which when position() is called on it will return undefined. Reason being `$(currLink.attr("href"))` is not selecting a DOM element, it's selecting arbitrary text, specifically the `href` attribute value of the `currLink` element.

Comment: But this plug is looking for the corresponding text in the anchors.  href="#home" & id="home"

Comment: @SethTipton then double-check your HTML. `refElement.position() === undefined` means `refElement` is empty.